# What is the correct response to a modbus request with too few data bytes?

Tags: modbus

In a Modbus server implementation, what response should the server send if it receives a request from the client that contains too few (or no) data bytes to interpret correctly?

For example, a modbus RTU server (with address 0x01) receives the ADU datagram: 0x01, 0x01, 0xE0, 0xC1.  In this case no physical transport layer errors are detected, the address is correct, the CRC is correct and the function (Read Coils) is correct and implented on the server, but the PDU does not contain the Starting Address or Quantity of Inputs fields required to process the request.

Should the server assume that a (very rare) bit error has occurred and not respond at all?
Should the server interpret this as 'a value in the query data field' being not allowed for the server and respond with an ILLEGAL DATA VALUE exception?
Should the server do something completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, at least with Modbus TCP, devices tend to just ignore malformed requests.

Comment: It does appear to be common practice to ignore them.  However, I'm trying to find out what is actually correct.  Section 7 of the MODBUS Application Protocol Specification V1.1b3 specification appears to suggest (to me at least) that the exception is required, as it explicitly states that the exception is not to be used to indicate range issues.  If not for this, when should it return an ILLEGAL DATA VALUE exception?

Comment: To answer the question in my previous comment, Figure 21 - the state diagram for 'Write Multiple Outputs (0x0F)' - shows that this exception is returned if the Byte Count does not match the number of outputs to be written.  I can't really tell what the difference is between that and the PDU containing the wrong number of bytes.  (In this case, the Byte Count field itself appears redundant to me.  Ho hum.)

Comment: It seems to me that all exception codes are defined for application layer problems - basically that everything in the spec is defined in the context of a well-formed request.

Answer (score 0):

From the specification [MODBUS APPLICATION PROTOCOL SPECIFICATION V1.1b3](http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b3.pdf) the exception (code 3) is correct. Figure 9 MODBUS Transaction state diagram clearly indicates the exception response to an incorrectly formed message.

I suspect the common response that rejects the message is indistinguishable from a transmission error, and the implementor of the faulty client will then be induced to correct their implementation.

Your suggestion that a communication error triggers this is possible, but only if the underlying link does not detect missing bytes. Any byte, other than 0xFF will introduce a start bit into a serial channel, and a missing byte in the TCP/UDP implementations is even less likely.

Comment: The meaning of the process 'Validate Data Value' in the flow diagram you cite is ambiguous.  Section 7 of the spec. says that exception code 3 is for when "A value contained in the query data field is not an allowable value for server."  But none of the flow diagrams for any of the functions indicate that the size of the request should be checked, only the values contained within it.  There lies my problem: malformed PDUs seem to fall outside the scope of the specification.

Comment: I suggest Validate Data Value applied equally to the number of registers and the mismatched length then results in it being invalid. Any protocol not formally specified is notoriously likely to contain ambiguities like this. In the exception code table, there is 'such as that the implied length is incorrect', covering this specific case. You're right that the flow charts of the individual functions do not cover this case.